# Permission boundaries: make sure roles can't create roles with more permissions than themselves, even when they have multiple attached policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Imagine the following scenario:

- I have a role that has multiple policies attached to it, specifying all the permissions the role has. Let's call it RoleA
- I need to attached multiple policies to RoleA because one policy with all the necessary permissions would break the policy's allowed chars limit (6144 chars per policy)
- RoleA needs to be able to create other roles and policies
- To prevent privilege escalation, I would like to put a condition that the roles created by RoleA need to have a permission boundary
- So that I don't have to manage multiple permissions boundaries, I would like the roles created by RoleA to have multiple permissions boundaries, these permissions boundaries being the policies I attach to RoleA
- With the above, I make sure that although RoleA can create roles, all the roles RoleA creates do not have escalated permissions, because the created roles need to have RoleA's policies attached as permissions boundaries

However, when a role is created, we can only specify one permission boundary. Like mentioned above, since RoleA has multiple permissions, I can't create a single permission boundary policy matching RoleA's permissions.

As far as I understand, this means that I, as an admin, either:

- Manage multiple permissions boundaries policies according to the created roles use case, and RoleA can pick the appropriate one for the roles they create
- Or I remove RoleA's permission to create roles, and instead manage the roles they need, still allowing them to use the roles as needed

My questions are:

- Is there a better approach?
- If there isn't a better approach, what's the best approach out of the two?